# How to define "number of cycles which make up a graph" as a graph invariant formally?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, invariance

I'll consider a graph (quiver) $E=(E^0,E^1,s,r)$, where $E^0$ is the set of vertices, $E^1$ is the set of arrows, and $s,r\colon E^1\to E^0$ are the source and range maps. I allow loops and multiple edges between two vertices.

Basically, I want to count "how many cycles make up the graph $E$". I am not sure how to define this invariant properly, or even if it is well-defined. So assuming it is a sensible graph property, it should define an invariant which depends only on the graph.

> **Question**: Is it possible to define "the number of cycles which make up a graph in a formal way?

I'll list a few examples of graphs which are "made up" of two cycles, intuitively

---

So for example, the following graph is "made up" of two cycles: $e$ and $f$

[image]

There is also another simple cycle (which does not repeat edges) in this graph: the path $ef$.

---

Now consider the following graph:

[image]

It is also "made up" of two simple cycles: the "left-right ones" $cdef$ and $abg$.

But we can also decompose it in more interesting ways: for example the "in-out cycles" $abcde$ and $fg$.

---

Let's modify the graph above a little:

[image]

It also seems to be made up of two cycles, but it is a little harder to do in this case: the simplest way I can see how to do it is as $baf$ and $gfcdef$. The latter cycle is not simple anymore, and in fact I am pretty sure the graph cannot be decomposed into disjoint simple cycles. But still, the invariant of this graph should be $2$.

Comment: Is it true that your last graph without **f** will have no cycles at all?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes. It will also not be strongly connected anymore (the source of $f$ becomes a sink).

Comment: Well... Clearly, the number of cycles in a non-oriented graph is of no help here. Then again, one could think of _all possible_ cycles, but that's not what you want either. All in all, I still don't see whether your invariant is well-defined. Let's wait for somebody more knowledgeable.

Comment: What role do $s$ and $r$ play in the property you are looking for?

Comment: @roundsquare Its just the definition of a directed multigraph and the op wanted us to know, which type of graphs he is using. Other than that it did not play a role in the considerations of the invariant yet...

Comment: Thanks @PrudiiArca. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to define the minimal number of cycles required, such that deleting their edges gives a cyclefree graph. As a minimum this should be well defined and I think it satisfies your conditions. Moreover edges, which are not part of a cycle, will not contribute to this invariant.

I think of a cycle to repeat neither vertices nor edges (besides start and endpoint), so in your first example $ef$ should not count as a cycle, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Then the last example should return 1 (by deleting _f_, you get a cyclefree graph). However, the OP thinks it must be 2.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but an edge is not a cycle, right? So deleting $f$ is not involved in finding my invariant. Yet you might be right that there could be a subtlety here, which I did not consider...

Comment: @PrudiiArca Yes, I *think* the invariant for the last one should be 2, but it could also just be that my intuition is not so precise. This idea of "removing cycles" is quite nice, actually, and I am working on it. Here's a question: If we have a graph $E$ as in the question and two families $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ of cycles s.t. removing either of those families of cycles gives a cyclefree graph, is $\#\mathcal{A}=\#\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: @Questioner This is indeed a nice question. Did you make any progress on that yet?